# how to find a sequence of numbers

Tags: bash, shell

I have a data file formatted like this:

```
0.00  0.00 0.00
 1   10  1.0
 2   12  1.0
 3   15  1.0
 4   20  0.0
 5   23  0.0
0.20  0.15  0.6
 1   12  1.0
 2   15  1.0
 3   20  0.0
 4   18  0.0
 5   20  0.0
0.001  0.33  0.15
 1   8   1.0
 2   14  1.0
 3   17  0.0
 4   25  0.0
 5   15  0.0
```

I need to remove some data and reorder line like this:

```
1  10
1  12
1  8

2  12
2  15
2  14

3  15
3  20
3  17

4  20
4  18
4  25

5  23
5  20
5  15
```

My code do not show anything. The problem might be in the grep command. Could you please help me out?

```
touch extract_file.txt
for (( i=1; i<=band; i++))
do
    sed -e '1, 7d' data_file | grep -w " '$(echo $i)' " | awk '{print $2}' > extract(echo $i).txt
    paste -s extract_file.txt extract$(echo $i).txt > data
done
#rm eigen*.txt
```

Comment: Please do let us know the logic behind getting expected output in your post.

Comment: The code you posted does something completely different from the expected output you want. Also `> data` the file `data` is overwritten each loop. `$(echo $i)` is just pointless, just remove the echo, it's just `$i`. The `sed '1, 7d'` removes first 7 lines, why would you do that? `grep -w` greps for words, yet in your regex you specified two spaces and two `'` singlequotes.

Comment: If you could clarify your requirements I am pretty sure we could do this task in a single program itself using one command probably.

Comment: `awk '/^ / {print $1,$2}' file | sort -ns`

Comment: `awk '/^ / {print $1,$2}' file | sort -ns | awk 'NR>1 && prev!=$1 {print ""} {prev=$1}1'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code with comments:

```
cat <<EOF |
0.00  0.00 0.00
 1   10  1.0
 2   12  1.0
 3   15  1.0
 4   20  0.0
 5   23  0.0
0.20  0.15  0.6
 1   12  1.0
 2   15  1.0
 3   20  0.0
 4   18  0.0
 5   20  0.0
0.001  0.33  0.15
 1   8   1.0
 2   14  1.0
 3   17  0.0
 4   25  0.0
 5   15  0.0
EOF
# remove lines not starting with a space
grep -v '^[^ ]' |
# remove leading space
sed 's/^[[:space:]]*//' |
# remove third arg
sed 's/[[:space:]]*[^[:space:]]*$//' |
# stable sort on first number
sort -s -n -k1 |
# each time first number changes, print additional newline
awk '{ if(length(last) != 0 && last != $1) printf "\n"; print; last=$1}'
```

outputs:

```
1   10
1   12
1   8

2   12
2   15
2   14

3   15
3   20
3   17

4   20
4   18
4   25

5   23
5   20
5   15
```

Tested on [repl](https://repl.it/@kamilcukrowski/OccasionalEllipticalExternalcommand).

Comment: Thank you so much! I just still have a question. If all lines start with space, then what should I do?

Comment: Then how do those `1` `2` lines differ from the other?

Comment: they do no start with integers.

Answer (score 0):

perl one-liner:

```
$ perl -lane 'push @{$nums{$F[0]}}, "@F[0,1]" if /^ /;
              END { for $n (sort { $a <=> $b } keys %nums) {
                     print for @{$nums{$n}};
                     print "" }}' input.txt
1 10
1 12
1 8

2 12
2 15
2 14

3 15
3 20
3 17

4 20
4 18
4 25

5 23
5 20
5 15
```

Basically, for each line starting with a space, use the first number as a key to a hash table that stores lists of the first two numbers, and print them out sorted by first number.